# Why there are not any sliders in my lightroom?

Tags: lightroom

[image]

Why there are not any sliders in my lightroom, how can i put sliders on the right?

Answer (score 6):

You're in the "Library" module, not the "Develop" module. Pull down the toolbar at the top (either hover over the grey arrow top-center of the screen for a temporary pull down, or click on it for permanent) and then click on the "Develop" module. The same result can be accomplish by Ctrl+D (on Windows).

Comment: pfffff so so simple, i am new in lightroom i need to familiarize my self. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You need to be in Developer Mode, right now you are in library mode, click the downwards arrow at the top section of lightroom.

[Lightroom Tutorials](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/tutorials.html)

Comment: thanks a lot, i need to familiarize my self in lightroom

Comment: another place to check is digital photography school, they also have lots of tutorials as well.